# Spring migration from 2.7.x to 3.1.1 caused problem with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring

Hello this is my class from older spring version and I neet to justify it to the newer one. I tried to do it with @Bean SecurityFilterChain but I can't find all parts from code I need, e.g. the csrf() is deprecated, the sessionManagament() is also deprecated, antMatchers doesn't exist ..

```
@Configuration
//@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private StatelessAuthenticationFilter statelessAuthenticationFilter;

  @Value("true")
  private Boolean securityEnabled;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if (!securityEnabled) {
      http.csrf().disable();
      return;
    }
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().antMatcher("/re/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/re/au/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .addFilterBefore(statelessAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for springboot 3.1.1 you can refer below code for security :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/", "/user/register",
                                "/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

CustomAuthentcationManager

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, your pattern helped me to do mine